# return data from child window or get uploaded filename

Tags: php

I have a from that gets several entries then inserts those into a database via post data. Which works just fine. I have a file upload form that renames and moves just fine. Where I am stuck is how to get the renamed file name into the form.

the way I have it 
user fills out form
there is a button to add a photo that launches a popup that will upload the file. once the file uploads the popup closes.

How can I get the renamed file name into the form so I can insert it into the database. I have tried this codebut I get c:\fakelocation\filname,

```
<form name ="frm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-          data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="photoname" id="photoname">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"      onclick="window.opener.frm.photoname.value=document.frm.photoname.value">
    </form>
```

could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

try to upload the file with ajax and get the renamed filename in the response of tha ajax